# UpdateAPIView not raising 404 when not exists in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**.

I have an endpoint to update existing record, extending **UpdateAPIView**

```
class FakeOrderPaymentView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderPaymentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        log.debug(self.request.data)
        order_id = self.request.data.get('order_id', None)
        if not order_id:
            raise Http404

        return self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.filter(pk=order_id).first()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = self.perform_update(serializer)
        instance_serializer = OrderListSerializer(instance)
        return Response(instance_serializer.data)
```

and the **OrderPaymentSerializer**

```
class OrderPaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True, required=False)
    order_status = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'order_status',
            'order_id'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        log.debug(validated_data)
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        status = validated_data.pop('order_status', None)
        order_id = validated_data.pop('order_id', None)
        instance.status = Order.STATUS.COMPLETED
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

The **order_id** and **order_status** are not model fields. They are just to carry data.

If `order_id` is not in the PUT data or `order_id` is blank. It should raise 404 response.

But, it's not calling `get_object()` method before `update()`.
Also, even if I pass `order_id` in the PUT data. The `perform_update()` method is calling serializer's `create()` method instead of `update()` method.

1. When is serializer's `update()` method called?
2. Why `get_object()` is not calling automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. When is serializer's update() method called?

As the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) states:

> Calling .save() will either create a new instance, or update an existing instance, depending on if an existing instance was passed when instantiating the serializer class

Since you are not providing an instance when instantiating the serializer, calling `save` will translate into `create` instead of `update`.

> 2. Why get_object() is not calling automatically?

Because you view's `update` method is overridden and you didn't call `get_object`. Default DRF `update` is:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)
```